# How do you update Yum repos in rh-cloud.repo on a GC instance to trusted ones?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redhat, yum

I have a Google Comput instance with Redhat 7 installed.  Suddenly I can no longer use Yum on the instance as all the repos are marked as untrusted. I get tons of errors like this running any Yum command:

```
https://cds.rhel.updates.googlecloud.com/pulp/repos///content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/7Server/x86_64/os/Packages/device-mapper-1.02.135-1.el7_3.5.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] curl#60 - "Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user."
Trying other mirror.
device-mapper-libs-1.02.135-1. FAILED
```

All the repos in /etc/yum.repos.d/rh-cloud.repo give this error. If remove that repo file, the error goes away, but Yum can't find any packages.

How do I update those repos to point to the correct, trusted, URL? (Or just get Yum to ignore the error, though that seems a little dodgy!)

Comment: Please raise this with Google or Red Hat customer support. It is very likely a subscription issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have a brute solution for this: disable ssl check.

In the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/rh-cloud.repo` I replaced all instances of `sslverify=1` with `sslverify=0`.

It allowed me to install the package I needed (`traceroute`).

Need to find another solution.